# How do I use Back to My Mac (to time capsule) in a multiple Airport configuration?

Tags: airport, time-capsule, back-to-my-mac

I have an Airport Extreme with an attached USB drive that I've been accessing via Back to My Mac using [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4907) (see the section with the text, "...access files on a hard drive connected to an AirPort Extreme...").

Recently I extended (over Ethernet) my Airport network using an Airport Express upstairs. i.e.

```
Airport Extreme with USB drive (downstairs) <--Ethernet--> Airport Express (upstairs)
```

I used [these instructions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21216656) (see the first post by Bob Timmons) to extend my network. I can tell that the network extension is over Ethernet because AirPort Utility shows both Airports connected to each other with a solid line (extension over WiFi uses a dashed line).

However, this makes my downstairs Airport Extreme disappear from Back to My Mac. Using Bonjour Browser on a remote Mac, I can see only the upstairs Airport Express:

```
#######.members.btmm.icloud.com - 4
  Airport Base Station (_airport._tcp.) - 1
    airport_upstairs
  Apple File Sharing (_afpovertcp.tcp.) - 2
    home_mac_1
    home_mac_2
```

Notice that only airport_upstairs is visible via Back to My Mac (even though airport_downstairs is the one configured for Back to My Mac). Has anyone else run into this problem--do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that only one Airport at a time is visible via Back to My Mac. I had Back to My Mac configured on *both* `airport_downstairs` and `airport_upstairs`. As soon as I disabled Back to My Mac on `airport_upstairs` and restarted both routers, `airport_downstairs` appeared in Back to My Mac.

I suspect that the last Airport to start up is the one that appears on Back to My Mac, though I haven't verified this.